# Tensorflow mixes up images and labels when making batch

Tags: python, image-processing, machine-learning, tensorflow, batch-processing

So I've been stuck on this problem for weeks. I want to make an image batch from a list of image filenames. I insert the filename list into a queue and use a reader to get the file. The reader then returns the filename and the read image file.

My problem is that when I make a batch using the decoded jpg and the labels from the reader, tf.train.shuffle_batch() mixes up the images and the filenames so that now the labels are in the wrong order for the image files. Is there something I am doing wrong with the queue/shuffle_batch and how can I fix it such that the batch comes out with the right labels for the right files?

Much thanks!

```html
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops


def preprocess_image_tensor(image_tf):
  image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image_tf, dtype=tf.float32)
  image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, 300, 300)
  image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
return image

# original image names and labels
image_paths = ["image_0.jpg", "image_1.jpg", "image_2.jpg", "image_3.jpg", "image_4.jpg", "image_5.jpg", "image_6.jpg", "image_7.jpg", "image_8.jpg"]

labels = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]

# converting arrays to tensors
image_paths_tf = ops.convert_to_tensor(image_paths, dtype=tf.string, name="image_paths_tf")
labels_tf = ops.convert_to_tensor(labels, dtype=tf.int32, name="labels_tf")

# getting tensor slices
image_path_tf, label_tf = tf.train.slice_input_producer([image_paths_tf, labels_tf], shuffle=False)

# getting image tensors from jpeg and performing preprocessing
image_buffer_tf = tf.read_file(image_path_tf, name="image_buffer")
image_tf = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_buffer_tf, channels=3, name="image")
image_tf = preprocess_image_tensor(image_tf)

# creating a batch of images and labels
batch_size = 5
num_threads = 4
images_batch_tf, labels_batch_tf = tf.train.batch([image_tf, label_tf], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=num_threads)

# running testing session to check order of images and labels 
init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(init)

  coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
  threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(coord=coord)

  print image_path_tf.eval()
  print label_tf.eval()

  coord.request_stop()
  coord.join(threads)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wait.... Isn't your tf usage a little weird?

You are basically running the graph twice by calling:

```
  print image_path_tf.eval()
  print label_tf.eval()
```

And since you are only asking for `image_path_tf` and `label_tf`, anything below this line is not even run:

```
image_path_tf, label_tf = tf.train.slice_input_producer([image_paths_tf, labels_tf], shuffle=False)
```

Maybe try this?

```
image_paths, labels = sess.run([images_batch_tf, labels_batch_tf])
print(image_paths)
print(labels)
```

Comment: Oh shoot you're right! This is exactly the problem. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

From your code I'm unsure how your labels are encoded/extracted from the jpeg images. I used to encode everything in the same file, but have since found a much more elegant solution. Assuming you can get a list of filenames, `image_paths` and a numpy array of labels `labels`, you can bind them together and operate on individual examples with `tf.train.slice_input_producer` then batch them together using `tf.train.batch`.

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.framework import ops

shuffle = True
batch_size = 128
num_threads = 8

def get_data():
    """
    Return image_paths, labels such that label[i] corresponds to image_paths[i].

    image_paths: list of strings
    labels: list/np array of labels
    """
    raise NotImplementedError()

def preprocess_image_tensor(image_tf):
    """Preprocess a single image."""
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image_tf, dtype=tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(image, 300, 300)
    image = tf.image.per_image_standardization(image)
    return image

image_paths, labels = get_data()

image_paths_tf = ops.convert_to_tensor(image_paths, dtype=tf.string, name='image_paths')
labels_tf = ops.convert_to_tensor(image_paths, dtype=tf.int32, name='labels')
image_path_tf, label_tf = tf.train.slice_input_producer([image_paths_tf, labels_tf], shuffle=shuffle)

# preprocess single image paths
image_buffer_tf = tf.read_file(image_path_tf, name='image_buffer')
image_tf = tf.image.decode_jpeg(image_buffer_tf, channels=3, name='image')
image_tf = preprocess_image_tensor(image_tf)

# batch the results
image_batch_tf, labels_batch_tf = tf.train.batch([image_tf, label_tf], batch_size=batch_size, num_threads=num_threads)
```

Comment: Alright I tried it this way and I'm getting the exact same problem. I'm now not sure if its my batch implementation or something to do with how I'm initializing the queue. Specifically, my problem is that I tested it with the same list of image paths as image_paths and a list of numbers 0-8 as labels. I printed out the first slice of images and labels and I got `image_path_tf = test_output/image_1.jpg` and `label = 4` (I would've expected the label to be 1). I did `print image_path_tf.eval()` and `print label_tf.eval()` between the `start_queue_runners` and the `request_stop`

Comment: I edited the above code to be what I have right now. Could you maybe show me how you would go about printing out the slices from 0-8 using queue runners/etc.? Thanks!