# Tensorflow shuffle_batch speed

Tags: tensorflow

I noticed a big difference in speed if I load my training data into memory and feed it into the graph as a numpy array vs using a shuffle batch of the same size, my data has ~1000 instances.

Using memory 1000 iterations takes less than a few seconds but using a shuffle batch it takes almost 10 minutes. I get the shuffle batch should be a bit slower but this seems way too slow. Why is this?

**Added a bounty. Any suggestions on how to make shuffled mini-batches faster?**

> Here is the training data: [Link to bounty_training.csv (pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/dNcqL9gN)

Here is my code:

> shuffle_batch

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

data = np.loadtxt('bounty_training.csv',
    delimiter=',',skiprows=1,usecols = (0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14))

filename = "test.tfrecords"

with tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(filename) as writer:
    for row in data:
        features, label = row[:-1], row[-1]
        example = tf.train.Example()
        example.features.feature['features'].float_list.value.extend(features)
        example.features.feature['label'].float_list.value.append(label)
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

def read_and_decode_single_example(filename):
    filename_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer([filename],
                                                   num_epochs=None)
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    features = tf.parse_single_example(
        serialized_example,
        features={
            'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], np.float32),
            'features': tf.FixedLenFeature([14], np.float32)})

    pdiff = features['label']
    avgs = features['features']

    return avgs, pdiff

avgs, pdiff = read_and_decode_single_example(filename)


n_features = 14
batch_size = 1000
hidden_units = 7
lr = .001

avgs_batch, pdiff_batch = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
    [avgs, pdiff], batch_size=batch_size,
    capacity=5000,
    min_after_dequeue=2000)

X = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,n_features])
Y = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,[None,1])

W = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_features,hidden_units]))
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([hidden_units]))

Wout = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([hidden_units,1]))
bout = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

hidden1 = tf.matmul(X,W) + b
pred = tf.matmul(hidden1,Wout) + bout

loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.squared_difference(pred,Y))

optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(lr).minimize(loss)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
    sess.run(init)
    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    for step in range(1000):
        x_, y_ = sess.run([avgs_batch,pdiff_batch])

        _, loss_val = sess.run([optimizer,loss],
              feed_dict={X: x_, Y: y_.reshape(batch_size,1)} )

        if step % 100 == 0:
            print(loss_val)


    coord.request_stop()
    coord.join(threads)
```

> Full batch via numpy array

```
"""
avgs and pdiff loaded into numpy arrays first...
Same model as above
"""
   with tf.Session() as sess:
        init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
        sess.run(init)

        for step in range(1000):
            _, loss_value = sess.run([optimizer,loss],
                    feed_dict={X: avgs,Y: pdiff.reshape(n_instances,1)} )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is instead of feeding single examples into shuffle_batch you feed an n+1 dimensional tensor of examples to it with enqueue_many=True. I found this thread that was very helpful:

[TFRecordReader seems extremely slow , and multi-threads reading not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41647784/tfrecordreader-seems-extremely-slow-and-multi-threads-reading-not-working)

```
def get_batch(batch_size):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()
    _, serialized_example = reader.read(filename_queue)

    batch_list = []
    for i in range(batch_size):
        batch_list.append(serialized_example)

    return [batch_list]

batch_serialized_example = tf.train.shuffle_batch(
 get_batch(batch_size), batch_size=batch_size,
    capacity=100*batch_size,
    min_after_dequeue=batch_size*10,
    num_threads=1, 
    enqueue_many=True)

features = tf.parse_example(
    batch_serialized_example,
    features={
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], np.float32),
        'features': tf.FixedLenFeature([14], np.float32)})

batch_pdiff = features['label']
batch_avgs = features['features']

...
```

Answer (score 3):

In this case, you're running a session 3 times per step - once in `avgs_batch.eval`, once for `pdiff_batch.eval`, and once for the actual `sess.run` call. That doesn't explain the magnitude of the slow down, but it's definitely something you should keep in mind. At the very least the first two eval calls should be combined to one `sess.run` call.

I suspect most of the slow-down is coming from use of `TFRecordReader`. I don't pretend to understand the inner workings of tensorflow, but you might find my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41864333/tensorflow-mixes-up-images-and-labels-when-making-batch-how-to-fix/41864611#41864611) helpful.

Summary

- create minimal data associated with each example, i.e. image filenames, ids rather than entire images;
- convert to tensorflow ops with `tensorflow.python.framework.ops.convert_to_tensor`;
- use `tf.train.slice_input_producer` to get a tensor for a single example;
- do some preprocessing on individual examples - e.g. load images from filenames;
- batch them together using `tf.train.batch` to group them up.

Comment: I read somewhere that the eval() only takes a few microseconds. I was thinking it was something with how the reader handles i/o. The time it takes to do one iteration of the training loops seems to be linear with the batch size I give it.

Answer (score 0):

When using queues to get the data, you shouldn't use feed_dict. Instead, make your graph depend directly on the input data, that is:

- remove the X and Y PlaceHolders
- use your feature batch directly

  ```
  hidden1 = tf.matmul(avgs_batch,W) + b
  ```
- similarly, use the label batch (pdiff_batch) instead of Y when computing the loss
- finally, just keep the second session.run to compute the loss directly, and without using feed_dict

  ```
  # x_, y_ = sess.run([avgs_batch,pdiff_batch])
  # _, loss_val = sess.run([optimizer,loss],
        feed_dict={X: x_, Y: y_.reshape(batch_size,1)} )

  _, loss_val = sess.run([optimizer,loss])
  ```